# Laravel - Can't upload the user in multiauth system

Tags: laravel, authentication, crud, registration, middleware

I am using multi auth login system. I made register, login and mail system. But i don't know how to make update function. Every member needs to update own profile. My problem is i can't get the related users details. id, name, etc...

In my **auth.php** customer guards was created:

```
'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ]
```

Also this is the **CustomerLoginController**:

```
class CustomerLoginController extends Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:customer')->except('logout', 'userLogout');
}

public function showLoginForm(){
    return redirect()->route('homepage');
}

public function login(Request $request){


    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'password'  =>  'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('homepage'));
    }
    return redirect('/')->with('error_login', 'Login Fail');
}

public function logout(Request $request) {

    Auth::guard('customer')->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

I added the `function show($id)` and `function update(Request $request)`

But as i told. Can't get the related user.

My last try is:

```
$user = Customer::find($id);
```

this is the right way to doing this i think. But i can't connect them. 
ps: i am not using --resources (crud). I must do that manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but have you tried using `auth()->user()` to get the current logged in user?

Comment: I think you need to get current user. Did you try `$user = Auth::guard('customer')->user()` to get current user